# Encontrar los divisores de un numero e identificar los primos

Tags: javascript

tengo una duda, esa primera parte está correctamente realizada, pero no se que codear para lograr retornar que "numero" es primo. Como puedo realizar por completo eso ???.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si `divisoresNumero` está vacío entonces regresa `"Es primo"`

Comment: puedes también validar si el arreglo tiene 2 elementos, porque para que sea primo debe tener siempre 2 elementos. Si la longitud del arreglo es igual 2, entonces es primo.

Comment: Como comenta @HeytalePazguato, al finalizar la comprobación de si existen divisores verifica si la longitud del arreglo es 0 (fuera del loop), de ser así muestra "Es primo"

Comment: Gracias @HeytalePazguato

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Añadiendo la siguiente declaración:

```
{
    
    for(let i = 2,raiz=Math.sqrt(numero); i <= raiz; i++)
        if(numero % i === 0) return false;
    return numero > 1;
}
```

No sé si podrá llamar a una sentencia ``` block ({ ... })````o puedes llamar a una función que guardes en una vinculación. Se podrá hacer de las dos formas.